# Finding the image of a function

Tags: real-analysis

If I have a function that is continuous on an interval I = (a,b). Say I wanted to find the image of this function. I intuitively felt like what you would do is take the the limit of f at a and b and see what the limits are, and then your image would be the interval of these two limits.

I'm not sure if this is entirely correct though. Could someone maybe point me in the direction of a theorem or some other idea that either supports or refutes this idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is not correct. For example, consider $f(x)=x^2$ on the interval $(-1, 1)$. At $-1$ and 1 this function is 1 but its image is actually $[0, 1)$.

One thing you can say is that the image is connected. Therefore if you can find the infimum and supremum of the function on $I$, you can determine its image (or at least its closure). Specifically, if the function is differentiable on $I$ then you can use the standard technique of checking critical points and limits as $x$ approaches the endpoints of the interval.